# Google +1 button: data-href

Tags: url, google-plus-one

I'm confused about Google+ +1 button. I have a web application and I've added a +1 button, but I'm not sure what URL I have to put on `data-href`.

It seems like you have to create a web page on your Google+ account and put this URL like `data-href`, and I've done so (`data-href="https://plus.google.com/+mywebsitename"`), but when you search the web page with Google, the number of +1 doesn't appear.

So I'm guessing that I should replace with: `data-href="http://example.com"`, but I'll lose the few +1 that I already have.

Any idea of how to handle this? I'm not interested on having better SEO on Google+ page, but the web application page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `data-href="http://example.com"` for the +1 button on your site. You've been doing it wrong, so you were collecting +1 for your G+ page instead of your website!

Don't worry, I'm sure you can collect +1s again!